# Show error messages in the web browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code

How do we display errors in an ASP.NET 5 MVC application, running with `DNX` (1.0.0-beta4-11566), in Visual Studio Code? Currently, I'm just receiving a white screen on the web browser.

Answer (score 3):

## Minimal Answer

In `project.json` add the following to the `dependencies` section.

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4"
```

In `Startup.cs` add the following using statement.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;
```

Then update the `Startup.Configure` method with this.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // other code omitted
    app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
}
```

As far as I know, this is the minimum configuration necessary to add an error message that looks like this:

[image: Server Side Error Message]